# Other element would receive the click issue using phpunit, selenium on chrome

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating some phpunit scripts that test some websites using selenium 2.  These tests are executed using the chrome browser. 1 of the tests is to confirm that it can locate a link on the page by using xPath, and then click on the link. But intermittently, the test will fail and reports the error:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a href="" ng-click="select()" uib-tab-heading-transclude="" class="ng-binding"> ...</a> is not clickable at point (708, 139). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-screen" style=""></div>
```

I have downloaded the latest chromedriver, but still get this error.
Has anyone experienced this error?
How did you get around this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error message explains the problem

> Element ... is not clickable at point (708, 139). Other element would receive the click: `<div class="modal-screen" style=""></div>`

The problem is that the element you are trying to click has another element, the `DIV`, on top of it which is blocking the click you are attempting. In my experience this is typically caused by a dialog or other UI element is on top of the desired element. In your case, looking at the HTML of the `DIV` element, it looks like the grey background behind some modal dialog is the culprit. If I were to guess, there are a few possibilities:

1. A dialog is up
2. You closed a dialog but it's not quite gone yet
3. Some loading, etc. spinner came up and you clicked before it was gone

To solve #1, just close the dialog. You might need to wait for the dialog to be invisible, see #2.

To solve #2 or #3, just wait for the `DIV` to be invisible and continue the test. You should be able to use `WebDriverWait` and wait for the CSS selector, `div.modal-screen` to be invisible.